# How can I debug user mode driver failures in Windows 8

Tags: drivers, windows-8, sd-card

I have a 32 GB SD Card.  Whenever I insert this card in to my newly upgraded Windows 8 laptop the OS stops responding normally. Metro Apps won't work. The system may or may not log in. Desktop apps may or may not be able to do things. When I remove the card and restart then all is fine. As soon as I put the card back in, the system starts misbehaving again.

I've run Windows Update, so I have the latest drivers from Microsoft.

This does **not** occur with the 8 GB cards I have.  Unfortunately I only have one 32 GB card, so I can't test with others.

From examining the system event log I've determined this is happening due to a user mode driver failure.

How can I best debug this issue from here?
How can I figure out which driver this is related to?
Will there be a Dr. Watson crash dump somewhere?

[image: Event 10110]

**Details**

```
- System 

  - Provider 

   [ Name]  Microsoft-Windows-DriverFrameworks-UserMode 
   [ Guid]  {2E35AAEB-857F-4BEB-A418-2E6C0E54D988} 

   EventID 10110 

   Version 1 

   Level 1 

   Task 64 

   Opcode 0 

   Keywords 0x2000000000000000 

  - TimeCreated 

   [ SystemTime]  2012-10-29T00:51:57.532718300Z 

   EventRecordID 40417 

   Correlation 

  - Execution 

   [ ProcessID]  1056 
   [ ThreadID]  3796 

   Channel System 

   Computer thebrain 

  - Security 

   [ UserID]  S-1-5-18 


- UserData 

  - UMDFHostProblem 

   [ lifetime]  {811E3DC4-FBC6-420B-ABCC-AD7505A36F3B} 
  - Problem 

   [ code]  3 
   [ detectedBy]  2 

   ExitCode 3 

  - Operation 

   [ code]  259 
   Message 72448 

   Status 4294967295
```

### Edit 1

So I tried using Debug View from SysInternals (you can get it here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx).

That gave me this information:
[image: debug view screenshot]

which is not especially helpful.

Then I tried connecting WinDbg to `WUDFHost.exe` (the process that seems to host user mode drivers) to see if it could catch the error.

Get it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/hardware/hh852363

Instructions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/hardware/ff554716(v=vs.85).aspx

That didn't help much. It didn't catch any exceptions as I'd hoped (which would point me to the cause of the crash at least). Here's the stack of one of the threads:
[image: WinDbg Stack Trace]

Comment: DebugView (Which I am a huge fan of) is only for monitoring debug output - before I had two monitors I'd run it in server/client mode and run the client with the above display on my laptop, so I could look at the debug output.

Comment: Yeah, I know.  I was hoping they had left some debug messages in their driver.  As you can see I got something, but not anything helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help, but have you tried the minidump files at C:\Windows\Minidump .
[MiniDump Files](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680369)

Comment: Unfortunately that directory doesn't exist.  It makes me wonder if I need to turn minidumps on or if they're in a different location in Win8.

Comment: I have Win8, and that is where they are stored for me... Here is a link to some generic info on enabling minidump but not specific to Win8... [link](http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f10/enabling-minidump-424566.html) as well as [link] (http://blog.nirsoft.net/2010/07/27/how-to-configure-windows-to-create-minidump-files-on-bsod/) Hope that helps a little....